# ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException No feature for name

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch node setup. When I query the index via curl command I get the expected output.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/one/employee/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
"query": {
"term": {
"emp_id":"4318W01149"
}
}
}'
```

but when I run similar query via browser I get the error

`http://localhost:9200/one/employee/?q=emp_id:4318W01149`

```
{"error":"ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [employee]]","status":400}
```

I'm on ES version 1.5.2

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot `_search` in `http://localhost:9200/one/employee/?q=emp_id:4318W01149`

should be

`http://localhost:9200/one/employee/_search?q=emp_id:4318W01149`